# How to find the angle of a non right angled triangle in a cube?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle

I have to find $\angle MHN$ ($\angle H$ in $\Delta HMN$). It is inside a cube that has side lengths of $12$ cm. $M$ is the midpoint of the diagonal $BD$ and $N$ is the midpoint of edge $GF$. Here's the diagram:

[image: Diagram]

I'm completely lost on how I would find $\angle MHN$  because the triangle is skewed if I try to imagine it in 3D (the top is further back than the bottom of the triangle).

I have however calculated the length of line $MH$, in exact form it is $3\sqrt{24}$ cm, which is also $14.696938...$ cm. I could also probably find the lengths of line $MN$ and $HN$ but I would need to know at least one other angle to find $\angle MHN$ using the sine or cosine rule.

I don't know how to figure out the size of another angle.

I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: You will use the definition of the scalar product to find the angle:  $$\cos\theta=\frac{\vec{HM}\cdot\vec{HN}}{|\vec{HM}||\vec{HN}|}$$

Comment: Suppose $H$ is at the origin, and $B$ is at the point $(12,12,12)$ (not that the particular number $12$ is of much importance).  Can you come up with what $\vec{HM}$ and $\vec{HN}$ are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Pythagorean theorem to find all sides of $\Delta HMN$ as follows
$$\text{in right}\ \Delta MLN, \ \ \ \ \ \  MN^2=ML^2+LN^2=12^2+6^2=180$$
$$\text{in right}\ \Delta MLH, \ \ \ \ \ \ MH^2=ML^2+LH^2=12^2+(6\sqrt2)^2=216$$
$$\text{in right}\ \Delta HGN, \ \ \ \ \ \ HN^2=HG^2+GN^2=12^2+6^2=180$$
**Method-1**: Let $\angle MHN=\angle HMN=\theta\ $ in isosceles $\Delta HMN$, then $\angle MNH=\pi-2\theta$. Using **Sine rule** in $\Delta HMN$ as follows
$$\frac{\sin\angle MHN}{MN}=\frac{\sin\angle MNH}{MH}\iff \frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{180}}=\frac{\sin(\pi-2\theta)}{\sqrt{216}}$$
$$\sin\theta\left(\cos\theta-\frac{3}{\sqrt{30}}\right)=0\quad \quad (\sin\theta\ne 0)$$
$$\therefore \ \theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{30}}\right)\approx \color{blue}{56.79^\circ}$$

**Method-2**: Since all three sides of $\Delta MHN$ are known hence use **Cosine rule** as follows
$$\cos \angle MHN=\frac{MH^2+HN^2-MN^2}{2(MH)(HN)}=\frac{216+180-180}{2(\sqrt{216})(\sqrt{180})}$$
$$\angle MHN=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{30}}\right)\approx \color{blue}{56.79^\circ}$$

Comment: thank you, this makes sense. However when I calculated MH earlier I got something different to yours, would you mind explaining how you found the length of LH? Becasue when using pythagorous theorem to find MH, my LH was different to what you used, I found my LH by doing  6squared+6squared

Comment: sorry there was a mistake, I just fixed it

Comment: I arrived at a different answer.

Comment: @AndrewChin OK, please let me know what your answer is or you can point out my mistake if any.

Comment: I've written an answer.  Please let me know if I've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I think I've found your mistake:  $$\frac{216+180-180}{2(\sqrt{216})(\sqrt{180})}=\frac3{\sqrt{30}}\neq\frac9{2\sqrt{30}}$$

Comment: @AndrewChin Oh, I was quite mistaken in calculation. Thank you so much. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $H$ is at the origin $(0,0,0)$ and $B$ is at the point $(12,12,12)$.  Then we can define vectors $\vec{HM}=(6,6,12)\implies|\vec{HM}|=6\sqrt{6}$ and $\vec {HN}=(12,6,0)\implies|\vec{HN}|=6\sqrt{5}$.  Let $\theta$ represent the angle between $\vec{HM}$ and $\vec{HN}$.  As a result, we have
\begin{align}
\cos\theta&=\frac{(6,6,12)\cdot(12,6,0)}{(6\sqrt6)(6\sqrt5)}=\frac{108}{36\sqrt{30}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{30}}\\
\theta&=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{30}}\right)\doteq56.789^\circ.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Calculate $MN$, $MH$, and $HN$. Then using generalized Pythagoras's theorem:
$$\cos\angle MHN=\frac{MH^2+HN^2-MN^2}{2\ MH\ HN}$$

Comment: Isn't that just cosine law?

Comment: It's the same thing